# Back button response in video call

Tags: android, video, videochat, back-button-control

I am building an android application having video call facilities. I have used pristine.io webrtc library. My problem is when I press back button I want to finish the activity and show a small video view in top right corner of the screen. Thus user can navigate other activities of the application. If a user touches the small video view, the original Activity restarts with full screen video. Can anyone help me telling how can I do this.

Comment: What have you tried? where is the exact problem?

Comment: I have tried transparent activity. But In that case there is no control over the application other than the transparent activity. 

I could not find any other component which is always visible even when the application is in background. The user need to navigate other functionalities of the application but the video component should be at top right corner.